# Как сделать что бы лейбл был в одну строку?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Как сделать Имя товара в одну строку так, как "Ссылка"? Пытался добавить класс лейблу и через css padding и margin, но тогда input вправо уходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

замените `col-lg-1` на `col-lg-3`.

Answer (score 3):

Добавить к классу `form-group` класс `col-lg-12`(тем самым он будет занимать все свободное место) и увеличить место для надписи перед input(т.е. изменить `col-lg-1` на `col-lg-2` или `col-lg-3`)

Comment: input вправо уходит и лейбл тоже

Comment: можешь выгрузить весь код, включая css, чтобы можно было разобраться?

Comment: ладно спасибо, я решил проблему тупо, но решил. Оставил просто только Имя вместо Имя товара.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к лейблу css свойство: word-wrap:normal;